# Tess4j (tesseract.getWords() stopped working after new Windows installation

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am working on a java project and part of it is reading Text from pdf files. I programmed that part months ago and it has worked since then. Last week my Windows Installation broke after an update and I reinstalled it.
Now Tess4j seems to not work anymore. It neither works on jar files I exported of older versions of my programm nor when I launch the newes version from the IDE (Intellij)

Here is the part of the code, which stopped working. It simply hangs on .getWords():

```
Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
tesseract.setDatapath(pathToTrainingData);
tesseract.setLanguage("deu");
tesseract.setTessVariable("user_defined_dpi", "100");
words = tesseract.getWords(img, ITessAPI.TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_WORD);
```

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I was tired yesterday and forgot to check if the "pathToTrainingData" is actually correct. I assumed it would be somewhere inside of the project directory but for some reason I descided, back when I programmed this, that it should be in the AppData folder. I copied it over from the old Windows installation and now the jar file works again but if I run the programm from within intellij it still hangs on .getWords(). I tried with multiple different java versions with the same result.

Comment: It works even after exporting a new jar file, but not if run directly from the IDE.

Comment: [tess4j](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j) source is available. You can debug through it.